# Selector from array - Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, selector

My requirement is to split some text to array, lets say

`"blabla32020|dmakdj9230|3023902|dkasdfj39|etcetc"`

And I will also have div's with same ids example:

```
<div id=blabla32020></div>
```

I want to change the background color of those to one color. And also to ignore if one element is not there (example if there is no div for dkasdfj39, then I should not get an error). I tried this but it gives me a Type error (showing an entermark in front of blabla32020) on Chrome.

```
var bdata = bookcaldates.innerHTML.replace(/-/g,"");
var bookdatesreference = bdata.split("|");
for(var i=0; i<bookdatesreference.length; i++) 
{bookdatesreference[i].style.color='white';}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple selector:

```
$('#' + stringToSplit.replace(/\|/g, ',#')).css('color','white');
```

Comment: I get the following error on google chrome:

Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
31082013PV1

Note: 31082013PV1 is the div ID. Btw somehow there's a space between # and 3

Comment: Did with removing tab characters.

bookcaldates.innerHTML = bookcaldates.innerHTML.replace(/-/g,"");
bookcaldates.innerHTML = bookcaldates.innerHTML.replace(/\|/g,",#");
bookcaldates.innerHTML = "#"+bookcaldates.innerHTML;
bookcaldates.innerHTML = bookcaldates.innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
bookcaldates.innerHTML = bookcaldates.innerHTML.slice(0, -2);
jQuery.noConflict();
$(bookcaldates.innerHTML).css('color','white');

Answer (score 0):

try this with jQuery:

```
for(var i=0; i<bookdatesreference.length; i++) 
{
   $('#' + bookdatesreference[i]).css('color', 'white');
}
```

Comment: <exception>: "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #↵31082013PV1"
a: "#↵31082013PV1"

Answer (score 0):

```
If($("#" + bookdatesreference[i]))
$("#" + bookdatesreference[i]).css('color','white')
```

Comment: <exception>: "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #↵31082013PV1"
a: "#↵31082013PV1"

Answer (score 0):

FINAL ANSWER:

```
bookcaldates.innerHTML = bookcaldates.innerHTML.replace(/-/g,"");
bookcaldates.innerHTML = bookcaldates.innerHTML.replace(/\|/g,",#");
bookcaldates.innerHTML = "#"+bookcaldates.innerHTML;
bookcaldates.innerHTML = bookcaldates.innerHTML.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
bookcaldates.innerHTML = bookcaldates.innerHTML.slice(0, -2);
jQuery.noConflict();
$(bookcaldates.innerHTML).css('color','white');
```